# I want to show and run .ipynb file on my webpage

Tags: python, web, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to show and run .ipynb file on my webpage so that if someone upload any .ipynb or want to view the already uploaded file same extension on the webpage/website itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what whether you want to provide users with an interactive notebook, or just want to render the (last run of) the notebook.

**I want to provide an interactive editor**:

In this case, you will need to install and run `jupyter notebook` on your server (similar to running jupyer notebook locally), make sure the port jupyter uses is open to the Internet, then tell people the server's IP address (or domain name) and which port to connect to. Beware that this could be a [security issue](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html) unless you trust the people that you give access, which is why by default recent versions of Jupyter also require token-based authentication.

**I just want a website to statically render the notebook** (similar to the notebook preview built into GitHub):

Jupyter comes with a command line interface that can convert a notebook to a static HTML file containing the (last run of) the notebook.

`jupyter nbconvert --to html mynotebook.ipynb`

This will produce a static HTML file `mynotebook.html` that you can upload to the server. (Any images are also conveniently encoded directly in the HTML file using the data URI scheme)

To automate this, you will need to automatically run the above command on the server to convert a file whenever someone uploads an `.ipynb` file.

**I just want a convenient way for people to preview .ipynb files on my server**:

You can use [nbviewer.jupyter.org](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org) for this. For example, if `mynotebook.ipynb` is hosted on your server at `www.example.com/mynotebook.ipynb`, people can preview it in their browser at `https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/www.example.com/mynotebook.ipynb`

Answer (score 0):

The one element case not addressed yet: I want to "run" the notebook and pass out the output as html:

Load the notebook:

```py
with open(notebook_file, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    nb = nbformat.read(notebook_file, as_version=4)
```

Execute it:

```py
ep = nbconvert.preprocessors.ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')
ep.preprocess(nb)
```

Convert it to HTML:

```py
html, resources = nbconvert.HTMLExporter().from_notebook_node(nb)
```

Return the HTML (Flask example):

```py
return flask.Response(html, status=200, mimetype="text/html")
```

This allows you to use the notebook like a template.  It may either produce different results each time by accessing a DB or web page for data, or you can pass in file names for it to use via environment variables.